# Debug slow angular-ui-router state change on Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, debugging, angularjs, mobile-safari, angular-ui-router

I'm writing an angular app, using angular-ui-router to manage states / routing.

On desktop browsers (Chrome / Safari) this is working fine. However, on Mobile Safari on IOS 6 on iPhone 4 (and to a lesser extend on IOS 7 on iPhone 5) changing state, via $state.go, can take anything up to 2 seconds.

I'm using ngTouch, so I don't think that it's the 300ms that the native click event takes to fire. ngClick attributes that don't call $state.go now seem to work pretty much instantaneously.

How can I debug this to find where the time is being spent?

Comment: Have you found a solution ? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

ngTouch doesn't work with the ui-sref directive. We used [fastclick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) to handle the click behavior, and removed ngTouch. The issue is that the directives step on each others events, and are in fact incompatible. You can see this by reading the implementation of both directives.

Comment: I've downvoted this as I don't think it answers my question with regards to debugging.

Comment: Like I said, it doesn't work with it, so the ngTouch functionality ***doesn't actually work***. If you want details, go read the source of the two like I did. You'll find that ui-sref swallows up click events using its own methods, so it never actually makes it to the ngTouch stuff. We ended up using fastclick.js instead of ngTouch, it works fine. I think in fact my answer is MORE useful to you than if I would have told you about how to read the source of the two directives (which is what I did) to see that they step on each-other.

Comment: I'm not using the ui-sref directive, so I don't think that's where the time is being spent. All our route changing is programmatic via `$state.go`, initially triggered by standard `ng-click' attributes. Also, my question is about how to debug the situation... Maybe I more accurately should have asked how to profile certain parts of the app on an iPhone.

Comment: You might try using Angular's Batarang extension to profile where time is being spent then.

Comment: How can he use Batarang on mobile Safari?  It's a Chrome plugin.

Comment: While not perfect solution, you could still use Chrome to find performance issues that affect Mobile and Desktop viewers.

Answer (score 1):

Use console.time to print out in the Mobile Safari Console, 
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consoletimelabel

...in association with the ui-router listeners :

- $stateChangeStart
- $stateChangeSuccess
- $viewContentLoading
- $viewContentLoaded

  ```
      /* EXAMPLE - INCREMENT THE TIMER 
         FOR EACH ONE OF THE LISTENERS, TO DETECT THE BOOTLENECK */

      // START TIMING NOW
      console.time('state_transition');
      /*
      http://devin-clark.com/what-you-might-not-know-about-chrome-devtools/
      */

          $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
               function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
               console.timeStamp('state_transition');
      });

      // STOP TIMER
      console.timeEnd('state_transition');
  ```

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-ui-router.html

Who knows, maybe for improving ui-router's reactivity on mobile devices, FutureState from UI-router's extras could be something worth to explore :

http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/future

...but the only way to be sure is to understand the innards of the mobile browsers and their DOM/JS/GPU's management/computing limitations in respect of desktop browsers.

It could be that ng-animate requires too much of a mobile browser by building the "next" template ahead of its appearance into the viewport. And yet it could be something completely trivial. 
Please let us know your progress.