# AngularJS Mobile View Issues

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a SPA with AngularJS, everything is working as I hoped except that I am running into issues regarding its appearance on mobile (I am using twitter bootstrap 3). The two issues in particular are:

- Vertical scrolling on mobile is very jerky and sometimes gets stuck
- On some pages the users mobile screen automatically zooms in on an input field, which is fine. However, I want to undo this zoom when they change partial; because otherwise when the user gets to the next partial everything is too zoomed.

I have had a look around and can't see an answer to these. I haven't put code in here, as it pretty much effects the whole site :) However, for a demonstration of the issue you can see on the site itself: www.objectivemoney.co.za.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE TO INCLUDE CODE**

***Index.html***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="omApp">
    <head>
        <title>OM</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Find your perfect planner | Quickly search for and compare verified, customer reviewed planners in your area with OM">
        <meta name="keywords" content="search,financial,planner,compare,verified,planners">

        <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Font-Awesome-master/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='toaster/toaster.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        
        <!-- load CSS files locally -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-slider-master/slider.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css" />
        
        <!-- sharethis -->
        <script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
        
 <script>
   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
   m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
   ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', { 'cookieDomain': 'none' });
 </script>
    
    </head>
        <body>
            <!-- create a navbar that is collapsable in a mobile view -->
            <nav id="navbar-example" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static" role="navigation" ng-controller="searchController">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">       <img id="navbarlogo" src="./img/logo/logo-white.png"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div collapse="isCollapsed" class="navbar-collapse bs-js-navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#/search">Search</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#/resources">Resources</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#/login">Planner Registration</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- create a logout sign that shows when a user is logged in, position this on the right of the navbar -->
                        <ul ng-show="authenticated === true" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right logoutlink ng-cloak">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a ng-controller="searchController" ng-click="logout(); changeAuth()">Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
                </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>      
        
        <!-- Create container for app views -->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- set empty div for views, autoscroll means that page scrolls to top when user clicks through -->
            <div ng-view autoscroll="true"></div>
        <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <footer>
                <div>
                        <div id="footershare" class="col-sm-6">
                                <span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span>
                                <span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
                                <span class='st_linkedin_large' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
                                <span class='st_googleplus_large' displayText='Google +'></span>
                                <span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email'></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="footercontact" class="col-sm-6">
                            <p>Contact: xxx@xxx.co.za | Copyright &copy;</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
        <div class="ng-cloak" ng-controller="searchController">
            <div ng-show="showBar" class="signupBox">
                <p id ="signupBox-text"><span ng-click="setCloseBar();setShowBar()" class="signupBox-close pull-right"><b>&times;</b></span><a id ="signupBox-text" href="#/mailinglist" ng-click="setCloseBar();setShowBar()">Join Our Mailing List To Stay Up To Date With The Latest Planning Advise And News.</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>            

        <!-- load angular and additional precompiled services -->
        <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
        <script src="vs-google-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angulartics.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angulartics-ga.min.js"></script>
        <script src="toaster/toaster.js"></script>
        <script src="ui-bootstrap-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-slider-master/slider.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/ng-optimizely/ng-optimizely.js"></script>
            
        <!-- load angular app -->
        <script src="modules/omApp.js"></script>
        
        <!-- load custom services -->
        <script src="services/services.min.js"></script>
        <script src="services/data.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- load angular controllers -->
        <script src="controllers/minified/searchController.js"></script>
        <script src="controllers/minified/resourcesController.js"></script>
        <script src="controllers/minified/plannerRegController.js"></script>
        
        <!-- directives -->
        <script src="directives/directive.min.js"></script>            
            
    </body>
    <!-- toaster-container that shows when a user log ins and log out [CURRENTLY THE TOASTER SHOWS FOR TOO LONG AND TIME OUT FUNCTION DOES NOT CHANGE TOASTER DISPLAY TIME] -->
    <toaster-container toaster-options="{'time-out': 2000}"></toaster-container>
</html>
```

***Home Partial***

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="homepage-jumbo-info col-sm-offset-7 col-sm-5">
            <div class="homepage-jumbo-info-header">
                <h1>We'll help you find a <br><b> planner</b>, hassle-free</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="homepage-jumbo-info-box">
                <h2 class="homepage-jumbo-info-boxheader"><b>Compare verified planners</b> in your area</h2>
                <input vs-google-autocomplete="options"         
                ng-model="searchquery.address.name" 
                vs-street-number="searchquery.address.streetNumber" 
                vs-street="searchquery.address.street"
                vs-city="searchquery.address.city"
                vs-state="searchquery.address.state"
                vs-country-short="searchquery.address.countryCode"
                vs-country="searchquery.address.country"
                vs-latitude="searchquery.lat"
                vs-longitude="searchquery.long" 
                type="text" 
                name="address"
                id="address"
                class="form-control homepage-jumbo-info-boxinput"
                placeholder="In which city / suburb do you live?">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group homepage-searchbutton homepage-jumbo-info-boxbutton">
                <p id="homepage-searchbutton-text"><a href="#/search" class="searchprofilefooter-link">SEARCH NOW&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid homepage-body-steps">
    <div class="col-sm-12 homepage-body-header">
        <h2><b>Find The Right Planner With 3 Simple Steps</b></h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 homepage-body-steps-info">
            <h4 class="homepage-body-icons"><img id="homepage-body-icons" src="img/icons/search.png"></img></h4>
            <h3 class="homepage-body-icons-title"><b>SEARCH</b></h3>
            <p class="homepage-body-icons-text">Search for independently verified planners in your local area that can meet your requirements.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 homepage-body-steps-info">
            <h4 class="homepage-body-icons"><img id="homepage-body-icons" src="img/icons/compare.png"></img></h4>
            <h3 class="homepage-body-icons-title"><b>COMPARE</b></h3>
            <p class="homepage-body-icons-text">Compare planners based on their offerings, qualifications and actual customer reviews.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 homepage-body-steps-info">
        <h4 class="homepage-body-icons"><img id="homepage-body-icons" src="img/icons/schedule.png"></img></h4>
        <h3 class="homepage-body-icons-title"><b>SCHEDULE</b></h3>
        <p class="homepage-body-icons-text">Click to automatically schedule a meeting with your chosen planner at a time that suits you.</p>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="row homepage-body-carousel-header">
        <div class="col-sm-12 homepage-body-header">
        <h2><b>Our Planners Partner With The Biggest Companies In South Africa</b></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row homepage-body-carousel">
        <carousel interval="myInterval" disable-animation="true">
            <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
              <img ng-src="img/sitephotos/{{slide.image}}.png" alt="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
            </slide>
        </carousel>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid homepage-body-video">
            <p class="homepage-body-video-text">Watch our short video to see how it works in more detail</p>
                <div class="videoWrapper">
                    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-rsr45s2mws" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
    </div>

<div class="container-fluid homepage-body-steps">
    <div class="col-sm-12 homepage-body-header">
        <h2><b>How OM Helps You</b></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 homepage-body-steps-info">
        <h4 class="homepage-body-icons"><img id="homepage-body-icons-how" src="img/icons/independent.png"></img></h4>
        <h3 class="homepage-body-icons-title"><b>INDEPENDENT</b></h3>
        <p class="homepage-body-icons-text">All of our advisers have been independently verified, helping you to avoid any sharks.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 homepage-body-steps-info">
            <h4 class="homepage-body-icons"><img id="homepage-body-icons-how" src="img/icons/user-review.png"></img></h4>
            <h3 class="homepage-body-icons-title"><b>USER REVIEWED</b></h3>
            <p class="homepage-body-icons-text">All of our advisers are reviewed by genuine users, helping you make sure that the adviser is the right match for you.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 homepage-body-steps-info">
            <h4 class="homepage-body-icons"><img id="homepage-body-icons-how" src="img/icons/tailored.png"></img></h4>
            <h3 class="homepage-body-icons-title"><b>TAILORED</b></h3>
            <p class="homepage-body-icons-text">Search functionality lets you specify your ideal adviser.</p>
    </div>
    </div>    

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4 homepage-body-steps-info">
        <h4 class="homepage-body-icons"><img id="homepage-body-icons-how" src="img/icons/quick.png"></img></h4>
        <h3 class="homepage-body-icons-title"><b>QUICK</b></h3>
        <p class="homepage-body-icons-text">No need for lengthy internet research, enquiry calls or getting hold of friends and family to help you.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-offset-right-2 col-sm-4 homepage-body-steps-info">
        <h4 class="homepage-body-icons"><img id="homepage-body-icons-how" src="img/icons/free-2.png"></img></h4>
        <h3 class="homepage-body-icons-title"><b>FREE</b></h3>
        <p class="homepage-body-icons-text">Our service is entirely free of charge.</p>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Jack

Comment: Can't seem to access the site

Comment: Hey. Just my luck. As soon as I post this my server goes down :( I will comment once it is up again. Sorry!

Comment: Hi. It is back up now. Sorry about that!

Comment: Checked the site. Yes, on mobile it seems to have a weird scrolling behaviour. Also - which page has the input zoom issue? Do you have any code that affects the scrolling? Can you paste it here so that we know what's causing the issue? You might want to tag the question with css as well.

Comment: Hi. So the zoom issue comes in when you click on the 'where you live' input box on the home page. When you click the input box it zooms in on it and then when you then click through to search now the zoom level will persist. This makes the profiles zoomed. I will post the relevant code in my question to see if that helps! Thanks!

Comment: Do remember to explain why that code exists - as in, why do you have code that affects the scroll - what is the intention behind it

Comment: Hi. Code added. To be honest I do not think that I have any code in there that should affect the scroll. I can't remember adding anything that would impact.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug slow angular-ui-router state change on Mobile Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274876/debug-slow-angular-ui-router-state-change-on-mobile-safari)